# Как запустить python скрипт из html при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: html, python, веб-программирование

Есть простая html страница с popup'ом.
Нужно запускать python скрипт при открытии попапа (попап открывается при нажатии на кнопку).
В скрипте есть цикл и он выполняется пока не получает данные из вне и когда цикл завершается - выводится информация, эту информацию нужно выводить в попап.
Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 5):

На кнопку можно повесить вызов Ajax скрипта, который пошлет запрос на сервер (там и будет этот самый код из питон скрипта) и выведет ответ сервера в попап.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://mysite.ru/script_for_popup",
    data: { 
        name: "Вася", 
        lastname: "Пупкин"
    },

    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Прибыли данные: " + msg );
    }
});
```

Вместо alert любой код для изменения попапа

https://jqbook.net.ru/ajax/jquery

Answer (score 3):

В javascript-обработчике нажатия на кнопку делать ajax-запрос к python-скрипту на сервере.

```js
var URL = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/794972/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=ru.stackoverflow'

var output = document.getElementById('output');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;

    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        response = ['<h4>Авторы ответов к этому вопросу</h4>'];
        for (var x = 0; x < data.items.length; x++) {
            response.push('<p>' + data.items[x].owner.display_name + '</p>');
        }
        output.innerHTML = response.join('');
    }
    else {
        alert('Ошибка! ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
    
    button.innerHTML = 'Нажми меня';
    button.disabled = false;
};

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    this.innerHTML = 'Загружаю...';
    this.disabled = true;
    
    xhr.open('GET', URL, true);
    xhr.send();
});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<button id="button">Нажми меня</button>
```